# Stripe API Authentication Failure

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm actually running according to LamaDev's video, but am having an issue authenticating the API key apparently.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y66RgYMAgSo&ab_channel=LamaDev, 1:09.

Although I am able to bring up the Stripe checkout UI, when I input a test card/transaction, I am getting a returned msg - You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'), with the follow 401 status code.

I am unsure where i'm messing up - or maybe i'm on a different version of packages.

Passwords are stored in the .env's respect to front end or a back end for secret/public API token.

```
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token);
  };

  console.log(stripeToken)

  useEffect(()=>{
    const makeRequest = async ()=>{
      try{
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment",{
          tokenId:stripeToken.id,
          amount:500, //cart.total*100
        })
        history.push("/success", {data:res.data});
      }catch{}
    }
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  }, [stripeToken, cart.total, history]) //dependancies

    return (
        <Container>
            <Header/>
            <Announcement/>
            <Wrapper>
            <Title>YOUR BAG</Title>
            <Top>
                <TopButton>CONTINUE SHOPPING</TopButton>
                <TopTexts>
                    <TopText>Shopping Bag(2)</TopText>
                    <TopText>Your Wishlist</TopText>
                </TopTexts>
                <TopButton type="filled">CHECKOUT NOW</TopButton>
            </Top>
            <Bottom>
                <Info>
                    {cart.products.map(product=>(
                    <Product>
                        <ProductDetail>
                            <Image src={product.img}/>
                            <Details>
                                <ProductName><b>Product:</b>{product.title}</ProductName>
                                <ProductID><b>ID:</b>{product._id}</ProductID>
                                <ProductColour color={product.colour}/>
                                <ProductSize><b>Size:</b>{product.size}</ProductSize>
                            </Details>
                        </ProductDetail>
                        <PriceDetail>
                            <ProductAmountContainer>
                                <Add/>
                                <ProductAmount>{product.quantity}</ProductAmount>
                                <Remove/>
                            </ProductAmountContainer>
                            <ProductPrice>{product.price*product.quantity}</ProductPrice>
                        </PriceDetail>
                    </Product>
                    ))}
                    <Hr/>
                </Info>
                <Summary>
                    <SummaryTitle>
                        ORDER SUMMARY
                    </SummaryTitle>
                    <SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItemText>Subtotal:</SummaryItemText>
                        <SummaryItemPrice>${cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                    </SummaryItem>
                    <SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shipping</SummaryItemText>
                        <SummaryItemPrice>$5.90</SummaryItemPrice>
                    </SummaryItem>
                    <SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount</SummaryItemText>
                        <SummaryItemPrice>$-5.90</SummaryItemPrice>
                    </SummaryItem>
                    <SummaryItem type="total">
                        <SummaryItemText>Total</SummaryItemText>
                        <SummaryItemPrice>${cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                    </SummaryItem>
                    <StripeCheckout
                      name="Lama Shop"
                      image="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1486366?v=4"
                      billingAddress
                      shippingAddress
                      description={`Your total is $${cart.total}`}
                      amount={cart.total * 100}
                      token={onToken}
                      stripeKey={KEY}
                    >
                      <Button>CHECKOUT NOW</Button>
                    </StripeCheckout>
                </Summary>
            </Bottom>
            </Wrapper>
            <Footer/>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

I am creating accessToken as below, using the TOKEN from the postman request where I login.

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/"
const TOKEN = "MY SIGNIN STRING, PROVIDED MY THE AUTHENTICATION"

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
    
});
```

The stripe js API request itself is below, and i'm unsure why the issue is being caused.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);


router.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      source: req.body.tokenId,
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "usd",
    },
    (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
      if (stripeErr) {
        res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Is `process.env.STRIPE_KEY` defined? The error suggests it isn't. https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication

Comment: Hi @JonathanSteele, it is defined in my .env file. Despite this, it isn't authenticating.

Comment: But can you actually log the correct value in the file you're using it in?

Comment: I'm able to console.log my user request in the file. I can also see on Stripe that API requests are being made to the account through the visual icon shown on the dev dashboard. Furthermore, console.log returns a stripeToken from the onclick event, but can't make a post request with the /checkout/payment. I also have it below, given the authorization note but still nothing. `export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: { authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`},
});`